# what is error : Can't convert from <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision. in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, error-handling

I have ran this piece of code before and never had an error.

```
 df.new <- df1

for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  df.new[j,] <- df1[j,]/df2$specificCol[j]
  
}
```

as a point example,

```
df1[1,1]/df2$specificCol[1] = 6.179306e-06
```

when I just manually want to set  df.new[1,1] with this number, I get the error.

```
df.new[1,1] <-6.179306e-06
```

this time however I get this error

```
Error: Assigned data `6.179306e-06` must be compatible with existing data.
i Error occurred for column `x1`.
x Can't convert from <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision.
* Locations: 1.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

how should I fix this error?

ps. thanks to @user20650, in case someone else needs this:
it was enough to write a`s.data.frame(df.new)` instead of `df.new` ( which turns back true for `is.data.frame(df.new)`.
I do not know why but this worked!

Comment: reproducible example `df = tibble::tibble(x=1L:2L); df[1,1] = 0.1`. If you use `df[[1]][1] = 0.1` notation to subset and select it does not error. Or you could use a data.frame.

Comment: @user20650, please post as an answer?

Comment: @BenBolker; I don't use this package and so I don't know what is the preferred way to do these things or if there is some function or whatnot. I think its best I leave it to someone who knows.

Comment: @Mathica, you could post this as an answer to your own question (encouraged). "Why" is because "tibbles" are data frames but have slightly different rules.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why this worked for you in the past and stopped working (perhaps there has been a change in the tidyverse that contains the `tibble` package, but I didn't run across anything obvious) but here's a short explanation of what's going wrong:

```r
df = tibble::tibble(x=1L:2L)
```

If we select `df[1,1]` we get:

```r
str(df[1,1])
# tibble [1 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# $ x: int 1
```

That is, we get a 1x1 tibble with type `integer`. When we try to replace this element with a non-integer value (e.g. `df[1,1] <- 1.2`), R complains.

There are a few ways to work around this.

- If we use `[[`-indexing rather than `[,` indexing, the `[[`-extraction gives us a *vector* rather than a tibble. `df[[1]][1] <- 1.2` works, and coerces the whole column to a `double` (floating point) type.
- `df <- as.data.frame(df); df[1,1] <- 1.2` also works, because base-R data frames have different rules from tibbles; in particular `df[,1]` is a vector rather than a data frame
- we could also explicitly convert the column to a double type; `df[[1]] <- as.double(df[[1]]); df[1,1] <- 1.2` also works.

Basically, tibbles say that even when `i` is a single-element vector, `df[,i]` is always a one-column tibble rather than being downgraded to a vector, and it's fussy about replacing elements with elements of a different type (even though *most* of the time R is very lax about allowing you to interconvert between different data types when it makes sense).